# Buy X Have Y automatically added for free

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, free-gift

The responses I read looked like they were a few years old...so maybe Magento has this now.

I want to have customers Buy boots get a free hat.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Still the same as a few years ago. There is not "free gift" shopping cart price rule: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart.html so you will need a custom module.

For Magento 1, see one of the old answers like [Offering a free gift with purchase of a particular product type like (Buy X products Get Y Free)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116692/offering-a-free-gift-with-purchase-of-a-particular-product-type-like-buy-x-prod)

For Magento 2, there are already commercial extensions, but you should be able to build it in the same way.

Comment: A much easier way is to use a third party module like the Special Promotions Pro from Amasty (https://goo.gl/9WxbA4). It really works for our needs.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is provided in magento simply follow the steps:

Follow the procedure:

1. Go to magento admin panel->Marketing->Promotions->Cart Price Rules
2. Click on add new rule
3. Fill in the rule information section.

[image]

4. Give the condition on which you would like to give Y free on buying X.

Here I have given a condition that buy 2 qty of a product from category 3 and get one free
[image]

5. in the action section
   [image: image description here]