# How to add product to cart by product id and customer id?

Tags: magento2, addtocart

**I want to add a product to customer cart by product id and customer id**

I think that way should be like this

> load quote session and set customer id and then add product .

can you help me to do this ?

Comment: Please review [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115929/magento2-how-to-add-a-product-into-cart-programatically-when-checkout-cart-pro/116055)

Comment: @PurushotamSharma thanks but in this link product adding to current cart ... i want load custom card by customer id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use below code to add product into cart using customer Id and Product Id

```
public function __construct(
    /* Add below dependencies */
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quoteModel,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->storeManager                 = $storeManager;
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    $this->quoteModel                   = $quoteModel;
    $this->productRepository            = $productRepository;
}
```

Add below code in your existing function:

```
try {
    $customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
    $quote    = $this->quoteModel->loadByCustomer($customer);
    if (!$quote->getId()) {
        $quote->setCustomer($customer);
        $quote->setIsActive(1);
        $quote->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
    }


    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
    $quote->addProduct($product, $qty);
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //echo $e->getMessage(); die;
}
```

**Updated**

For adding the multiple products into cart, You can use like below where `$products` is array of product Ids.

```
foreach ($products as $productId) {
    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
    if ($product->getId() && $product->isVisibleInCatalog()) {
        try {
            $request = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(['qty' => 1]);
            $quote->addProduct($product, $request);
            $count++;
        } catch (\Exception $e) { }
    }
}
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

Hope this help !!

Comment: how i can set custom price to product in cart ?

Comment: how can i add multiple products to the cart?

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: I can add multiple product in cart but i can not see the price for that product.

Comment: i have also created question for this can you look into that https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215162/magento-2-how-to-add-product-to-cart-by-customer-id

Comment: In the above functionality how can i set the custom price to the product