# How to add product to the cart with customer id and product id magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, product, customer, addtocart, quoteitem

Actually while adding product to the cart with product id and customer id, i am facing one error "We found an invalid request for adding product to quote."
If anyone have any idea please guide me.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Vendor\Module\Api\CustomerServiceInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollection;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory as ProductFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface as StoreManager;


class Customerservice implements CustomerServiceInterface
{

    private $productCollection;
    private $ProductFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;

    protected $_product;
    protected $_customerserviceFactory;
    protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

    protected $_quoteModel;

    protected $_productRepository;

    protected $_cartManagementInterface;

    protected $_cartRepositoryInterface;

    public function __construct(ProductCollection $productCollection,
        ProductFactory $ProductFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\CustomerserviceFactory $customerserviceFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quoteModel,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $cartManagementInterface,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepositoryInterface,
        StoreManager $_storeManager)
    {
        $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
        $this->ProductFactory = $ProductFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $_storeManager;
        $this->_customerserviceFactory = $customerserviceFactory;
        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
        $this->_quoteModel                   = $quoteModel;
        $this->_productRepository            = $productRepository;
        $this->_cartManagementInterface = $cartManagementInterface;
        $this->_cartRepositoryInterface = $cartRepositoryInterface;
    }

    public function customerservice($params) {


        $customerId = 13;
        $productId = 81;     
        try {
            $product = $this->ProductFactory->create()->load($productId);
            $params = array(
                        "product" => $productId,
                        'qty' => 1,
                        "price" => 160
                    ); 

            $request = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $request->setData($params); 
            $quoteId = $this->_cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCartForCustomer($customerId);
            $quote = $this->_cartRepositoryInterface->get($quoteId);
            $customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
            $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
            $productAddToCart = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
            $quote->addProduct($productAddToCart, $request);
            $this->_cartRepositoryInterface->save($quote);
            $quote->collectTotals();
            //$quote->collectTotals()->save();


            echo json_encode("product added");
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            print_r($ex->getMessage()); exit;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Actually i tried this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196578/how-to-add-product-to-cart-by-product-id-and-customer-id  then its showing error "We found an invalid request for adding product to quote."

Comment: Can you please share your code.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya please check updated question

Answer (score 0):

use Magento\Framework\App\State as AppState;
protected $_appState;
public function __construct(AppState $appState){
   $this->_appState              = $appState;
}

$this->_appState->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);
Missing set Area

Hope help.