# Add item(s) to cart programmatically with different line

Tags: magento2, product, php, addtocart

I tried to add a product to cart programmatically, but it should be in different line with other product in the cart.

I already tried the code below but it only adds a product to cart and adds the qty if there's same product in the cart. How can I make it to a new line rather than add the qty?

**Add product code :**

```
$cartObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$cartObj->addProduct($_product,$params);
$cartObj->save();
```

Comment: Please refer the following link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115929/magento2-how-to-add-a-product-into-cart-programatically-when-checkout-cart-pro

Comment: I know that link help to add product to cart programmatically, but it's not help to add product to cart programmatically in new line like i describe in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add custom options to the $_product with

```
$customOptions = [
    'label' => 'test',
    'value' => 'value different by product (line)'
];
$_product->addCustomOption('custom_option', serialize($customOptions));
```

Before add product in cart