# Magento 2: I just need to add custom product in cart with custom price using observer

Tags: magento2

I have used this event for add product with a custom price: `checkout_cart_product_add_after`

its working fine for cart page. but when I redirect to checkout page then my custom product price has replaced with the original price which is already set in admin.

is there any way to save this custom price for place order whole process?

i used below code for add product with custom price :

```
            $params = array(
                'product' => $productIds,
                'qty' => 1
            );
            $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productIds);
            //echo "<pre/>"; print_r($_product->getData()); exit;
            $_product->setPrice(0);
            $this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$params);
            $this->_cart->save();
```

is there any event to save this custom price for end of order?
and which one code I used for that?

Comment: i updated my answer , it will help you to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Create an `events.xml` and hook to `checkout_cart_product_add_after`

> **NOTE:** $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true) in order to make $item->setCustomPrice() and $item->setOriginalPrice() work.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="modulename-customprice" instance="Companyname\Modulename\Observer\CustomPrice" />
    </event>
</config>
```

and

```
<?php

    namespace Companyname\Modulename\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

    class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
    {
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
            $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');         
            $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
            $price = 100; //your custom price here , you can make it dynamic as well ( use config values)
            $item->setCustomPrice($price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        }

    }
```

`checkout_cart_update_items_after` have a look this event as well as it runs for every items in cart.

**Must read** :

1) [Magento2 - How to add a product into cart programatically when checkout_cart_product_add_after is fired](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115929/magento2-how-to-add-a-product-into-cart-programatically-when-checkout-cart-pro)

2) [Create custom events](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html)

Comment: i want to add one additional product and update price of that product.

Comment: Let me  try to merge your code with my condition.

Comment: you can use the same execute function to create a product/or add a already created product and than update the total price,I didn`t tried but it seems that it will surely work , because we have a point `checkout_cart_product_add_after`  from where we can change the cart values

Comment: any idea about which one event i need to use for add product in cart? and then after which event use for update this cart price ?

Comment: you can try `checkout_cart_product_add_after` , but  i never tried to do the same, no idea currently. I am even trying to find the perfect solution which are stable as well

Answer (score 0):

Change `$_product->setPrice(0);` to `$_product->setCustomPrice(0);`

Comment: Its not working.