# How can i add a single gift for every order?

Tags: magento2, orders, extensions

Hello I want to be able to give a product that I will have in the 2 magento with every purchase. So I would like that when adding a product I would automatically add it to the cart, but there could only be one product of these that I am giving, I mean?

I have Magento 2.2.4

Edit:

Now i must put the product gift with SKU right?

[image]

And then add the free_gift attribute to the product that I want a free product to be given, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve what you want is to create a custom module for this. You can follow below approach for this.

1) Create a product attribute for example: free_gift_sku with type as dropdown and enter sku of all the free gift products. Associate this attribute with each products

2) Now while creating the product, select the free_gift_sku value as the SKU of the product which is required to be added as free gift for that product.

3) Observe an event checkout_cart_product_add_after and get the details of the product added to the cart through quote_item. You will get all the details of the product which also includes SKU of the free gift product.

4) Now programmatically add the free gift product to the basket. You can define the logic of adding the product as per your requirement.

Please Note: The code for observer and adding product to basket programatically is different for Magento1.x and Magento2.x. Digging into the code/Googling it will help you out.

To save you some time, please check this thread to add product to cart programmatically in Magento2

[Magento2 - How to add a product into cart programatically when checkout_cart_product_add_after is fired](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115929/magento2-how-to-add-a-product-into-cart-programatically-when-checkout-cart-pro)

Hope it helps

Comment: I edited my post, can you help me step by step? @Kirti Nariya

Comment: You can check my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for aaaaaaaaaaall your help... @Kirti Nariya